# Javascript Calendar.setup get selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar

I'am editing an existing system and they are using Calendar.setup instead of jquery datepicker. I already suggested that the datepicker is more upgraded than calendar.setup but then, they still want to use calendar.setup.

My Problem is, I dont know how to get the value of selected date.

```
 Calendar.setup
    (
        {
            inputField  : 'txtDate',       // ID of the input field
            ifFormat    : "%Y-%m-%d",       // The Date Format
            button      : 'txtDate'      // ID of the button
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 Calendar.setup
    (
        {
            inputField  : 'txtDate',       // ID of the input field
            ifFormat    : "%Y-%m-%d",       // The Date Format
            button      : 'txtDate',      // ID of the button
            onSelect    : function(){
                              var calDate = this.selection.get();
                              var calHours = new String(this.getHours());
                              var calMinutes = new String(this.getMinutes());
                              var calTime = ((calHours.length == 1) ? '0'+calHours : calHours) + ((calMinutes.length == 1) ? '0'+calMinutes : calMinutes );
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: You may want to give a short explanation of your code.

Comment: Hi, I found this post helpful. But a few question,  the date being fetch is like this "20140520", how do i format it to "Y/m/d"?

Comment: Figured it out, we can use the this.selection.print(format, separator). Documentation for reference: http://www.dynarch.com/jscal/

Answer (score 0):

```
var cal=Calendar.setup
    (
        {
            inputField  : 'txtDate',       // ID of the input field
            ifFormat    : "%Y-%m-%d",       // The Date Format
            button      : 'txtDate',      // ID of the button

        })
var seldate=cal.date
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!